# How to calculate weighted average in netcdf files

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray, weighted-average, netcdf4

I had netcdf file with dimensions `1400*2300*10`, `Latitude=1400`, `Longitude=2300`, `Height=10`

I know how to calculate average within Netcdf file for the Height Dimension

```
Dataset.mean(dim=Height)
```

I would like to know that If there is any predefined function to calculate weighted average with weights (3, 5, 2, 1, 0.8, 3.2, ...up to 10 random values).

Comment: Xarray has a `weighted` method under development but its not available in a released version of the code. You may want to take a peak at https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/422 where there is a simple work around and discussion about the upcoming feature.

Comment: I already seen this, my question is how to add weights manually (outside from netcdf data)?